# Protractor opens and closes the chrome browser immediately without running the full scenario

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I have written one scenario to test the application using protractor. My application starts with login page which is non-angular page then, after logging in moves on to the angular page.

Below is the javascript code snippet that i used to run:

```js
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var expect = chai.expect;
var myStepDefinitionsWrapper = function () {
    this.Given(/^that I login with valid user credentials$/, function (callback) {
        console.log("I'm in before URL");
        browser.driver.get('http://localhost:8000/#');
        console.log("I'm in after URL");
        browser.driver.wait(function() {
            console.log("I'm in Wait");
            return browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.xpath("//input[contains(@placeholder,'Username')]"));
        },10000);
        browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//input[contains(@placeholder,'Username')]")).then(function(username) {
            console.log("I'm in Username");
            username.sendKeys("welby");
        });
        browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//input[contains(@type,'password')]")).then(function(password) {
            console.log("I'm in Password");
            password.sendKeys("asdf");
        });

        browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();
        console.log("I'm after click");
        callback();
    });

     this.When(/^I click perform button in Tasks window$/, function (callback) {
         browser.waitForAngular();
         element(by.xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'Smith, Sally')]]/following::td[2]/button[text()='Perform']")).click();
         console.log("Clicked Perform");
         callback();
    });
}
```

Output:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 10.0.4\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" node_modules\protractor\lib\cli.js E2E\protractor-conf.js Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub [launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver 

 - I'm in before URL  
 - I'm in after URL
 - I'm after click
 - Clicked Perform

1 scenario (1 passed)  3 steps (3 passed)

[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running [launcher] chrome #1 passed

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Looks like the scenario has run completely and successfully. All milestones in your code are printed and WebDriver has quit. What step or portion of code above do you think is not executed?

Comment: It has not entered username and password methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the style of the code in your question you appear to be using Cucumber.js for your test runner. In this case then, you should be able to omit the `callback` parameter to your step definitions and simply return a promise:

```
this.Given(/^that I login with valid user credentials$/, function () {

    // The rest of the code remains the same.

    return browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();
});
```

And:

```
 this.When(/^I click perform button in Tasks window$/, function () {
     browser.waitForAngular();
     return element(by.xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'Smith, Sally')]]/following::td[2]/button[text()='Perform']")).click();
});
```

The capability of Cucumber.js to use promises is documented [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js#promises).

Protractor is built on Selenium. I strongly suggest reading the entire ["Understanding the API" section](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Understanding_the_API) of the Selenium documentation so that you understand how the JavaScript version of Selenium uses and sequences promises.

The reason your code is not working right now is that by calling `callback()` like you do you are telling Cucumber.js that your step is finished **before** Protractor (and Selenium) has actually performed the actions you want. When you return a promise, Cucumber.js waits until the promise is resolved or fails before moving on.

Comment: Observation: for some reason, when Louis answers, I scroll much more.

Comment: Thanks Louis. I removed the callback statements and at the end of the methods using returns as u shown. It is working for me.